# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'tns:root_element'

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema

I have spent past 2 hours on this. Am unable to figure out why this error is occurring. I have a simple xsd and xml code

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<element name="root_element" type="string"/>   
</schema>
```

xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root_element>"asd"</root_element>
```

My java code is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
SchemaFactory s_factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
dbf.setSchema(s_factory.newSchema(new File(schemafile)));  
dbf.setValidating(true);
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
CommodityPropsErrorHandler cp_eh = new CommodityPropsErrorHandler();
db.setErrorHandler(cp_eh);
Document doc = db.parse(new File(props_file));
```

Any comments would be helpful. regards

Comment: That can't be everything.  Somewhere there's a reference to a namespace prefix `tns:` that you haven't posted.

Answer (score 3):

I think that main issue is with:

```
dbf.setValidating(true);
```

According to Java API, [`DocumentBuilderFactory.setValidating`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setValidating%28boolean%29):

> Specifies that the parser produced by this code will validate
>   documents as they are parsed. By default the value of this is set to
>   false.
>
> Note that "the validation" here means a validating parser as defined
>   in the XML recommendation. In other words, it essentially **just
>   controls the DTD validation**. (except the legacy two properties
>   defined in JAXP 1.2.)
>
> To use modern schema languages such as W3C XML Schema or RELAX NG
>   instead of DTD, you can configure your parser to be a **non-validating
>   parser** by leaving the setValidating(boolean) method **false**, then
>   use the **setSchema(Schema)** method to associate a schema to a parser.

Also you don't need:

```java
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
```

Your working code probably is just (however I don't know what is in `CommodityPropsErrorHandler` class):

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
SchemaFactory s_factory =
    SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
dbf.setSchema(s_factory.newSchema(new File(schemafile)));  
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
CommodityPropsErrorHandler cp_eh = new CommodityPropsErrorHandler();
db.setErrorHandler(cp_eh);
Document doc = db.parse(new File(props_file));
```

Here is second, alternative approach with previous `dbf.setValidating(true);` (that is, using this two properties from JAXP, mentioned in Java API):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setValidating(true);

dbf.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage",
    XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
dbf.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource",
    new File(schemafile));

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
CommodityPropsErrorHandler cp_eh = new CommodityPropsErrorHandler();
db.setErrorHandler(cp_eh);
Document doc = db.parse(new File(props_file));
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is for making validation namespace aware. Otherwise it will give Element not present in the doc.

```
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
```